# dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true) not working when click outside the dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I use `DialogFragment` to create/show the `dialog`.

Additionally, I want to dismiss the dialogue when I click outside of the dialogue.

I tried calling `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` method after a dialogue is created but it is not working.

I tried some solutions from other posts, but still not working.

Where is the problem?

Here is my code `DialogSelectCategory.java`

```
<!-- language: java -->
public class DialogSelectCategory extends DialogFragment {
    static final String tag = "DialogSelectCategory";
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Activity act = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        String title = getResources().getString(R.string.select_category);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(act).inflate(R.layout.dialog_category, null, false);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        return dialog;
    }

    public void showDialog(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        this.show(fragmentManager, tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your dialog_category.xml . It may be possible if it is covering whole screen . Cause i have tested your code its working at my end .

Comment: @ADM Since you mentioned, I use CoordinatorLayout at first. 
But now I try using LinearLayout, I can dismiss the dialog. Thanks.
So, the dialog's view must not be CoordinatorLayout ?

Comment: CoordinatorLayout is for scrolling tricks mostly in Activities. You don't have to use CoordinatorLayout in dialog view.

Comment: I want to have some scroll effect in dialog. So, it is not suggested to do that according to the Design Principle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring when you are using DialogFragment to display Dialog

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html, the solution is to override `onCancel` in DialogFragment

```
// DialogFragment, not Dialog
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved, because I changed CoordinatorLayout to LinearLayout in my dialog xml.

Comment: Good! bravo. Happy Coding